# Fail2Ban fails to ban Asterisk Errors

Tags: regex, asterisk, fail2ban

I have fail2ban 0.9.1 with Asterisk 11 on Fedora 21 using IPTables.

The IP addresses that attack my server are not getting written to IP Tables automatically (see below about them working when manually running banip).  Do you see any errors that would be causing this?

I get messages in my /var/log/asterisk/messages log about miscreants trying erroneous extensions.

My Regex works because when I run

```
 fail2ban-regex /var/log/asterisk/messages /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk.conf
```

I get

```
 Lines: 2985 lines, 0 ignored, 597 matched, 2388 missed [processed in 0.66 sec]
```

This means that 597 lines matched the regular expression.  Right?  Is there a way to show what lines were matched?  and what the variables were?

I can also do:

```
 fail2ban-client set asterisk banip 107.150.44.222
```

and IPTables is properly updated and the IP is banned.  (Yes, I know I used a real IP address -- and as far as I am concerned everyone is welcome to ban the ba$%*$#rd)

```
 jail.local 

 [asterisk]
 enabled=yes
 filter=asterisk
 protocol=all
 logpath = /var/log/asterisk/messages
 banaction=iptables-multiport
 port     = 5060,5061
 action   = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, port="%(port)s", protocol="tcp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-tcp]
       %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, port="%(port)s", protocol="udp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-udp]
       %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s"]
 maxretry = 3
 bantime=432000
 findtime =86400
```

I removed the reference to Asterisk in jail.conf to avoid conflicts

```
 filter.d/asterisk.conf 

 [INCLUDES]

 # Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
 # common.local
 before = common.conf

 [Definition]

 # Option:  failregex
 # Notes.:  regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile.
 # Values:  TEXT
 #
 log_prefix= \[\]\s*(?:NOTICE|SECURITY)%(__pid_re)s:?(?:\[\S+\d*\])? \S+:\d*

 failregex = ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - Wrong password$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - No matching peer found$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - Username/auth name mismatch$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - Device does not match ACL$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - Peer is not supposed to register$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - ACL error \(permit/deny\)$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - Not a local domain$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Call from '[^']*' \(<HOST>:\d+\) to extension '\d+' rejected because extension not found in context 'default'\.$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Host <HOST> failed to authenticate as '[^']*'$
        ^%(log_prefix)s No registration for peer '[^']*' \(from <HOST>\)$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Host <HOST> failed MD5 authentication for '[^']*' \([^)]+\)$
        ^%(log_prefix)s Failed to authenticate (user|device) [^@]+@<HOST>\S*$
        ^%(log_prefix)s (?:handle_request_subscribe: )?Sending fake auth rejection for (device|user) \d*<sip:[^@]+@<HOST>>;tag=\w+\S*$
        ^%(log_prefix)s SecurityEvent="(FailedACL|InvalidAccountID|ChallengeResponseFailed|InvalidPassword)",EventTV="[\d-]+",Severity="[\w]+",Service="[\w]+",EventVersion="\d+",AccountID="\d+",SessionID="0x[\da-f]+",LocalAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/[\da-fA-F:.]+/\d+",RemoteAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/(<HOST>)/[0-9]{4}"(,Challenge="\w+",ReceivedChallenge="\w+")?(,ReceivedHash="[\da-f]+")?$

 # Option:  ignoreregex
 # Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
 # Values:  TEXT
 #
 ignoreregex =
```

Answer (score 0):

Your asterisk.conf and jail.local entry look fine, though I typically add the jail name after the banaction. For example: `banaction=iptables-multiport[name=asterisk]`

Restart the fail2ban service and check your fail2ban log for any errors. A common one that didn't get fixed until v0.9.2 is:

`Error in FilterPyinotify callback: 'module' object has no attribute '_strptime_time'`

To fix it, update fail2ban to v0.9.2 or edit the file: `/usr/share/fail2ban/common/__init__.py`

and add the following text to the end of the file:

```
from time import strptime
# strptime thread safety hack-around - http://bugs.python.org/issue7980
strptime("2012", "%Y")
```

> Is there a way to show what lines were matched? and what the variables were?

You'll want to use the **-v** option with fail2ban-regex. It won't give you matched variables, but will list each IP Address associated with the matched line. You can then examine details for that IP in your asterisk logs.

`fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/asterisk/messages /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/asterisk.conf`